# Можно ли взять такой элемент из одного массива, что любой элемент из второго массива не прибавляй, то сумма будет всегда меньше заданного числа

Tags: python, массивы, numpy, broadcasting

Как реализовать следующую задачу: можно ли взять такой элемент из 1 массива, что какой бы элемент из второго массива ни прибавляй, то сумма всегда будет меньше 7?

Например, есть два массива:

```
a = np.array([2,1,7])
b = np.array([3,4,5])
```

Да, можно, если взять единичку из первого массива: 1 + [3, 4, 5] = [4, 5, 6] - все элементы такой суммы меньше 7.

**Подскажите, как это сделать без цикла, если обратиться к broadcasting?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]**

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Нужно проверить условие: минимум первого массива + максимум второго массива < N. Совсем без циклов не получится, для того, чтобы найти минимум и максимум нужно перебрать элементы массивов. Ну, вернее, если можно использовать готовые функции, то явного цикла не будет, он будет "под капотом".

Comment: @CrazyElf Сделали бы ответом, тут больше нечего добавить

Comment: А причем тут метка broadcasting? Что бы все подумали, что это какой-то очень умный и сложный вопрос?

Comment: Автор вопроса сперва задал его в нормальной форме, а затем решил его зашифровать

Comment: @MBo Ну ок, хотя я всё-равно сомневаюсь - нужно ли было давать ответ, может человеку лучше было самому подумать )

Answer (score 2):

Нужно проверить условие:

```
минимум первого массива + максимум второго массива < N
```

Если смотреть на алгоритмическом уровне, то без циклов не получится: для того, чтобы найти минимум и максимум нужно перебрать элементы массивов. Но если можно использовать готовые функции, а не смотреть на алгоритмическую сложность, то явного цикла не будет, он будет "под капотом":

```
a = np.array([2,1,7])
b = np.array([3,4,5])
n = 7
print('можно' if a.min() + b.max() < n else 'нельзя')
```

Вывод:

```
можно
```

Зачем в данном случае нужен `broadcasting` - непонятно. Можно, конечно, его специально использовать, но решение будет менее оптимальное по сложности вычисления (а может и наоборот - смотря как происходит расчёт):

```
print('можно' if (a.min() + b < n).all() else 'нельзя')
```

Тут я прибавил минимум первого массива ко всем элементам второго массива, а потом проверил, что все они меньше `n`. Таким образом, бродкастинг был использован, аж два раза.

Answer (score 1):

Пусть число - X, а максимальный элемент второго массива - M.
Тогда любой элемент A (необязательно минимальный) первого массива, такой, что `A < X-M`, будет соответствовать этому условию. В первом массиве может быть несколько (или ни одного) числа, соответствующего условию.

```
a = np.array([0, 2, 1, 7])
b = np.array([3, 4, 5])
X, M = 7, b.max()
c = a[a < X - M]
if c.size:
    print(f'Такие элементы: {c}')
else:
    print('Таких элементов нет')
```

```
Такие элементы: [0, 1]
```

Comment: Кстати, мысль хорошая. Только лучше использовать `(a < X - M).any()` и тогда это может быть чуть эффективнее, чем мой вариант с минимумом `a`. В задачке же нужно сказать, что такие элементы в принципе есть, их список не нужен. И если `any` не "жадно" работает, то, возможно, это имеет смысл.